# In Python 3 how can a Parent class use a member from its children's global environment?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I have the following parent class in a separate file:

```
class Parent:
    def parent_method(self, class_obj arg):
        pass # do some other stuff
```

I have the following child class in another separate file:

```
from ModuleA import class_name
import Parent

class Child(Parent):
        def child_method(self, class_name, arg):
            class_obj = globals()[class_name]
            super().parent_method(class_obj, arg)
```

As you can see, the sole function for the Child class is to retrieve the `class_obj` from its global environment and then pass it on to its parent.
Because they belong to different files, their global environments are different so I cannot do this directly from the Parent. I have many such Child classes residing in different files. Is there a way to let the Parent handle this logic directly? Thanks.

Comment: If possible, try to redesign the solution entirely. Relying on `globals` for things like this is a warning flag that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @csl, thanks for the hint. but I'm afraid in my case it has to be a global. I am importing a sqlalchemy mapped class from another file. The child is passing a query to Parent, which handles query and filter logic. I really don't see any room for redesigning in this case.

Comment: If you absolutely have to do it this way, can't you just create a registry where you register class objects so that you can use them everywhere? Registry.add(YourClass, "name") is called from relevant files, it's stored one place, then anyone can do Registry.get("name") ?

Comment: @csl Thanks for suggesting this new route. Registry is a great idea, only you will have to do the 'registering' in every Child file. Do you think there is way to let the Parent to actively reach out and find all its children's global environment?

Comment: There might, but I think having children register themselves is much cleaner, and as your program scales, it will probably turn out to be a better idea.

Comment: @csl as the best practice, would you suggest putting such a registry as Parent's class attribute, or instance attribute? I can see merits for both but couldn't decide on which one is better. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure whether I understand your question. I was suggesting you create an entirely separate Registry class (which must be a singleton) and use that.

Comment: I'm unsure whether I understand your question. I was suggesting you create an entirely separate Registry class (which must be a singleton) and use that.